# Python typing: How to specify type aliases with third party types?

Tags: python, software-design, mypy, python-typing

I am still halfway new to python typing and have encountered a problem.

In my project I have some functions that pass or return very nested types.

Today I discovered that you can assign aliases with python typing.
I did that, but unfortunately mypy showed me a lot of errors.

The problem is that the type I wanted to give an alias to contains a type that is not from the normal typing package.

At the moment i use https://github.com/ramonhagenaars/nptyping to type my numpy arrays.

One of the types i wanted to give an alias to is the following:

```
 List[List[Tuple[NDArray[(Any,), int], NDArray[(Any,), int]]]]
```

mypy interpreted the NDArray type as "Any" and therefore I could not give this type an alias.
If I assigned this type to an alias and typed the functions with it I got an error message:

```
result_comparator.py:22: error: Invalid type alias: expression is not a valid type
result_comparator.py:22: error: Value of type "Type[List[Any]]" is not indexable
```

When I replaced the numpy array types with types like int or str the aliases worked.

I know that this is a very nested type and I am trying to restructure the type and the function. One way or another I would like to make the code more readable by using aliases.

Is there a way to give an alias to such a type too?
Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Was the NDArray properly imported before you tried to define the type?

Comment: `nptyping` isn't compatible with mypy anyway (and its design decisions are a terrible fit for NumPy in the first place).

Comment: (Actually, it looks like there was a big overhaul since the last time I checked, so `nptyping.NDArray` fits much better with NumPy than the old `nptyping.Array` did. It's still incompatible with mypy, though, and it really needs some way to express how the dimensions of arrays relate to each other.)